# What would be the simplest way to daemonize a python script in Linux?

Tags: python, scripting, daemon

What would be the simplest way to daemonize a python script in Linux ? I need that this works with every flavor of Linux, so it should only use python based tools.

Comment: One note -- PLEASE provide a way to run your program in the foreground, both for debugging and folks who prefer process supervision tools (such as runit [http://smarden.org/runit] or daemontools [http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html]) to run your program as a supervised service rather than a daemon.

Comment: Yes, I agree (I'm using daemontools)

Comment: related: [How do you create a daemon in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/473620/4279)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See [Stevens](http://www.kohala.com/start/) and also this [lengthy thread on activestate](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/278731/) which I found personally to be both mostly incorrect and much to verbose, and I came up with this:

```
from os import fork, setsid, umask, dup2
from sys import stdin, stdout, stderr

if fork(): exit(0)
umask(0) 
setsid() 
if fork(): exit(0)

stdout.flush()
stderr.flush()
si = file('/dev/null', 'r')
so = file('/dev/null', 'a+')
se = file('/dev/null', 'a+', 0)
dup2(si.fileno(), stdin.fileno())
dup2(so.fileno(), stdout.fileno())
dup2(se.fileno(), stderr.fileno())
```

If you need to stop that process again, it is required to know the pid, the usual solution to this is pidfiles. Do this if you need one

```
from os import getpid
outfile = open(pid_file, 'w')
outfile.write('%i' % getpid())
outfile.close()
```

For security reasons you might consider any of these after demonizing

```
from os import setuid, setgid, chdir
from pwd import getpwnam
from grp import getgrnam
setuid(getpwnam('someuser').pw_uid)
setgid(getgrnam('somegroup').gr_gid)
chdir('/')
```

You could also use [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) but that does not work well with [python's subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-subprocess.html)

Comment: Interesting. How do you start/stop the daemon ?

Comment: After demonizing I write a pidfile

Comment: Okay, so after that I can use a standard init.d script with your examples, it should do the trick.

Comment: @FlorianBösch Why nohup does not work well with Python's subprocess module? I'm experiencing same kind of problem. Pool is not working when I use nohup. I'm looking for the reason.

Answer (score 4):

[nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)

[Creating a daemon the Python way](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/278731/)

Answer (score 2):

I have recently used [Turkmenbashi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Turkmenbashi/1.0.0.01) :

```
$ easy_install turkmenbashi
import Turkmenbashi

class DebugDaemon (Turkmenbashi.Daemon):

    def config(self):
        self.debugging = True

    def go(self):
        self.debug('a debug message')
        self.info('an info message')
        self.warn('a warning message')
        self.error('an error message')
        self.critical('a critical message')

if __name__=="__main__":
    d = DebugDaemon()
    d.config()
    d.setenv(30, '/var/run/daemon.pid', '/tmp', None)
    d.start(d.go)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care for actual discussions (which tend to go offtopic and do not offer authoritative response), you can choose some library that will make your tast easier. I'd recomment taking a look at [ll-xist](http://www.livinglogic.de/Python/Download.html), this library contains large amount of life-saving code, like cron jobs helper, daemon framework, and (what is not interesting to you, but is really great) *object-oriented XSL* (ll-xist itself).

Answer (score 0):

Use [grizzled.os.daemonize](http://www.clapper.org/software/python/grizzled/):

```
$ easy_install grizzled

>>> from grizzled.os import daemonize
>>> daemon.daemonize()
```

To understand how this works or to do it yourself, read [the discussion on ActiveState](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/278731/).