# How to run python program as a daemon?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I write the following program to run my program as a daemon but it is not getting run; when i run the program from python debugger it works.

I am using Mac os x.

`/User/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.bobbob.osx.test.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd >
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>com.bobbob.osx.test</string>
<key>Program</key>
<string>/Users/vivekbhintade/Desktop/test.py</string>
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

`/Users/vivekbhintade/Desktop/test.py`:

```
import urllib2
from datetime import datetime
import smtplib
from smtplib import SMTPException
import threading

def checkerror():

    #my code which works fine individually, which sends mail after 5 seconds to recipients.

checkerror()
```

And also i run the program from terminal with following command.

```
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.bobbob.osx.test.plist
```

This does not result in any errors.

Comment: does `launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.bobbob.osx.test.plist ` work?

Comment: yes it work means it does not giving any kind of error msg

Comment: But does `launchctl` also send the email you expect? How do you run it from the terminal? With `$ python test.py`? It seems to me that `#!/bin/env python` is missing at the beginning of your file, so the os doesn't know how to run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [launchctl](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html)?

I believe this stack answers your question:

[Running Python in background on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522324/running-python-in-background-on-os-x)

Answer (score 2):

You have almost certainly realised this in the intervening 3 months since posting, but there seems to be some confusion here between **Launch Daemons** and **Launch Agents** which I though it would be worth clearing up - especially since Agents are often referred to as Daemons.

Paraphrasing the [Apple Developer library:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/DesigningDaemons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW4-BBCBHBFB)

- Daemons run as root at startup, are unable to present UI elements, and are located in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/`.
- Agents run in a user context at login, and are able to present UI elements to the user. These are located in `/Users/username/Library/LaunchAgents/`.

Your program will not run as it's located in `/User/Library` - it needs to go into one or another of the paths mentioned above, depending on how you plan to use it.