# Unix .pid file created automatically?

Tags: unix, pid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference for proper handling of PID file on Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688343/reference-for-proper-handling-of-pid-file-on-unix)

Is the .pid file in unix created automatically by the operating system whenever a process runs OR should the process create a .pid file programmatically like "echo $$ > myprogram.pid" ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688343/reference-for-proper-handling-of-pid-file-on-unix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter holds true -- a process must create the .pid file (the OS won't do it). `pid` files are often used by daemon processes for various purposes. For example, they can be used to prevent a process from running more than once. They can also be used so that control processes (e.g. `apache2ctl`) know what process to send signals to.

Comment: so you mean a process has to explicitly create `.pid` file?