# Python daemon no pidfile

Tags: python, daemon

Hello I'm writing a daemon in python which uses the python-daemon module, my application starts correctly, there is a pidfile.lock created but no sign of the pidfile containing the process id.

```
import daemon
import lockfile

import perfagentmain

context = daemon.DaemonContext(
    working_directory='/opt/lib/perf-agent',
    umask=0o002,
    pidfile=lockfile.FileLock('/var/run/perf-agent.pid')
    )


with context:
    perfagentmain.start()
```

Comment: `pidfile = daemon.pidlockfile.PIDLockFile("/var/run/zebra.pid")` — worked for me. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13082597/159149

Answer (score 9):

I agree with @npoektop 's comment about the solution. I would just say that `daemon.pidlockfile` does not exist at the time I am writing this. `daemon.pidfile` instead. Maybe that's a recent name change?

So instead, here's the general solution using the `daemon.pidfile` module instead of the `lockfile` module.

```
import daemon
import daemon.pidfile
import perfagentmain

context = daemon.DaemonContext(
    working_directory='/opt/lib/perf-agent',
    umask=0o002,
    pidfile=daemon.pidfile.PIDLockFile('/var/run/perf-agent.pid')
    )

with context:
    perfagentmain.start()
```

And @Martino Dino, you're absolutely right, it seems the `lockfile` module has a totally different implementation of writing lock files. (even though `python-daemon` actually requires `lockfile`)

When I tried out `pidfile = lockfile.FileLock('/var/run/mydaemon.pid')` for my own needs, I instead saw a file called `<MY_MACHINE_NAME>-<8CHAR_HEX_ID>.<PID_OFF_BY_2>`, along with a file `/var/run/mydaemon.pid.lock` .  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/688365/472876) mentions how this method of hard linking a randomly named file to your pidlock file was a file-locking method prior to the use of the `O_EXCL` flag used when opening files.

But the annoying part was that the file did not contain the PID as you said, and the *file name had a PID which was off by a few numbers of the correct PID*, so it was terribly misleading.