# get python deamon pid after create of context

Tags: python, pid

with python-deamon, it's possible to print pid of this deamon ?
i want like this :

```
import daemon

context = daemon.DaemonContext()
with context():
    do_main_program()
print("pid of deamon : " + str(context.pid))
```

thanks for advance

Comment: Is this related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909754/python-daemon-no-pidfile

Comment: no, i want pid, no pidfile

Comment: What is the output of your print statement? what is the output of `print(dir(context))`?

Comment: it's return list of argument :
['chroot_directory', 'close', 'detach_process', 'files_preserve', 'gid', 'initgroups', 'is_open', 'open', 'pidfile', 'prevent_core', 'signal_map', 'stderr', 'stdin', 'stdout', 'terminate', 'uid', 'umask', 'working_directory']