# How can I right a cronjob to delete some pid files on my RHEL server on reboot?

Tags: bash, cron

The server I work on had an ungraceful shutdown due to power failure but when it came up my application didn't come up since the pids for the services before shutdown still existed. This impacted services on my server and I am looking for a way to create a cronjob that will look for existing pid files on boot and if they exist delete them.

Comment: Are you probably looking for the @reboot primitive in the crontab?

Comment: Well I am looking for a way of deleting the stale pid files using @reboot primitive in a  cronjob

Comment: Have you already checkout this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40205638/detecting-a-stale-pid-file-in-a-unix-environment