# What python modules are available to assist in daemonization in the standard library?

Tags: python, daemon

I have a simple python program that I'd like to daemonize.

Since the point of my doing this is not to demonstrate mastery over the spawn, fork, disconnect , etc, I'd like to find a module that would make it quick and simple for me. 
I've been looking in the std lib, but can not seem to find anything.

Is there?

Comment: Holy smokes! Why did nobody mention supervisord?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a library for making well behaved unix daemons: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/

And another one that appears more lightweight:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/278731/

Answer (score -1):

```
subprocess
```

is an (almost) platform-independent module to work with processes.

Comment: More details would be very helpful.

Comment: `subprocess` is not the right tool for daemonization.  Instead, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/473620/489590 or [python-daemon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/).