# How to run a script in the background even after I logout SSH?

Tags: python, service, cron

I have Python script `bgservice.py` and I want it to run all the time, because it is part of the web service I build. How can I make it run continuously even after I logout SSH?

Answer (score 282, accepted):

Run `nohup python bgservice.py &` to get the script to ignore the hangup signal and keep running. Output will be put in `nohup.out`.

Ideally, you'd run your script with something like [`supervise`](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/supervise.html) so that it can be restarted if (when) it dies.

Comment: when I run command with nohup and &, I get message `nohup: ignoring in
put and appending output to `nohup.out'`
and when I press enter the process exits with status 1. What's going on?

Comment: read the output in nohup.out. in my case, it was a permissions problem, i needed to use sudo

Comment: and how to stop the bgservice after it is run in this method?

Comment: @Shaegorath save the pid somewhere so that you can send signals to the process later.  in some shells (bash, zsh, etc.) after you do `somecommand &` it will print the pid like `[1] 12345`.  otherwise you can use `$!`.

Comment: I have been looking at nohup as the recommended solution to the question, but I see that the output file nohup.out is generated after the python script ends. It does not allow you to append the results as the python script runs. I also don't see how you provide inputs to the scripts using nohup. I haven't tested the behavior of threads but it is not a good solution for me for the above reasons. So I will keep looking. Any solutions or suggestions? I want to interact with my application when I log back in using ssh.

Answer (score 44):

If you've already started the process, and don't want to kill it and restart under nohup, you can send it to the background, then disown it.

`Ctrl+Z`  (suspend the process)

`bg`   (restart the process in the background

`disown %1` (assuming this is job #1, use `jobs` to determine)

Comment: How do I get it to stop printing to the standard output?

Answer (score 37):

#### Running a Python Script in the Background

First, you need to add a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line in the Python script which looks like the following:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

This path is necessary if you have multiple versions of Python installed and `/usr/bin/env` will ensure that the first Python interpreter in your `$$PATH` environment variable is taken. You can also hardcode the path of your Python interpreter (e.g. `#!/usr/bin/python3`), but this is not flexible and not portable on other machines. Next, you’ll need to set the permissions of the file to allow execution:

```sh
chmod +x test.py
```

Now you can run the script with [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) which ignores the hangup signal. This means that you can close the terminal without stopping the execution. Also, don’t forget to add `&` so the script runs in the background:

```sh
nohup /path/to/test.py &
```

If you did not add a `shebang` to the file you can instead run the script with this command:

```sh
nohup python /path/to/test.py &
```

The output will be saved in the `nohup.out` file, unless you specify the output file like here:

```sh
nohup /path/to/test.py > output.log &
nohup python /path/to/test.py > output.log &
```

If you have redirected the output of the command somewhere else - including `/dev/null` - that's where it goes instead.

```sh
# doesn't create nohup.out

nohup command >/dev/null 2>&1
```

If you're using `nohup`, that probably means you want to run the command in the background by putting another `&` on the end of the whole thing:

```sh
# runs in background, still doesn't create nohup.out

 nohup command >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

You can find the `process` and its `process ID` with this command:

```sh
ps ax | grep test.py

# or
# list of running processes Python

ps -fA | grep python
```

`ps` stands for `process status`

If you want to stop the execution, you can [kill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_(command)) it with the kill command:

```sh
kill PID
```

Comment: what if I want it still accept standard input from ssh terminal before I exit the ssh?

Comment: The topic talks about the background and not about the standard execution. Anyway, I think your answer is in this [great documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: This is a great and very complete answer. Thanks @MilovanTomašević

Answer (score 19):

Alternate answer: `tmux`

- ssh into the remote machine
- type `tmux` into cmd
- start the process you want inside the `tmux` e.g. `python3 main.py`
- leaving the `tmux` session by `Ctrl+b` then `d`

It is now safe to exit the remote machine. When you come back use `tmux attach` to re-enter `tmux` session.

If you want to start multiple sessions, name each session using `Ctrl+b` then `$`. then type your session name.

to list all session use `tmux list-sessions`

to attach a running session use `tmux attach-session -t <session-name>`.

Answer (score 17):

You could also use [GNU screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) which just about every Linux/Unix system should have.

If you are on Ubuntu/Debian, its enhanced variant [byobu](http://byobu.co) is rather nice too.

Answer (score 15):

You might consider turning your python script into a proper python daemon, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9047339/482352).

[python-daemon](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) is a good tool that can be used to run python scripts as a background daemon process rather than a forever running script. You will need to modify existing code a bit but its plain and simple.

If you are facing problems with python-daemon, there is another utility [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/introduction.html) that will do the same for you, but in this case you wont have to write any code (or modify existing) as this is a out of the box solution for daemonizing processes.

Comment: giving a brief explanation about how the problem can be solved is generally a good idea.

Answer (score 8):

You can nohup it, but I prefer [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple solution inside python using a decorator:

```
import os, time

def daemon(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if os.fork(): return
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        os._exit(os.EX_OK)
    return wrapper

@daemon
def my_func(count=10):    
  for i in range(0,count):
     print('parent pid: %d' % os.getppid())
     time.sleep(1)


my_func(count=10)
#still in parent thread
time.sleep(2)
#after 2 seconds the function my_func lives on is own
```

You can of course replace the content of your `bgservice.py` file in place of `my_func`.

Comment: Maybe it is necessary to catch the SIGHUP signal. Then add signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, handler) in your block.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't seem to work here. The child dies when the parent exits.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
nohup python -u <your file name>.py >> <your log file>.log &
```

You can run above command in **screen** and come out of screen.

Now you can tail logs of your python script by: `tail -f <your log file>.log`

To kill you script, you can use **ps -aux** and **kill** commands.

Comment: what if I want it still accept standard input from ssh terminal before I exit the ssh?

Answer (score 3):

The [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/) shell has an option to make all background processes run with nohup.

In `~/.zshrc` add the lines:

```
setopt nocheckjobs  #don't warn about bg processes on exit
setopt nohup        #don't kill bg processes on exit
```

Then you just need to run a process like so: `python bgservice.py &`, and you no longer need to use the nohup command.

I know not many people use zsh, but it's a really cool shell which I would recommend.

Answer (score 1):

If what you need is that the process should run forever no matter whether you are logged in or not, consider running the process as a daemon.

[supervisord](http://supervisord.org/introduction.html) is a great out of the box solution that can be used to daemonize any process. It has another controlling utility `supervisorctl` that can be used to monitor processes that are being run by supervisor.

You don't have to write any extra code or modify existing scripts to make this work. Moreover, verbose documentation makes this process much simpler.

After scratching my head for hours around python-daemon, supervisor is the solution that worked for me in minutes.

Hope this helps someone trying to make python-daemon work

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **Yapdi**:

Basic usage:

> ```
> import yapdi
>
> daemon = yapdi.Daemon()
> retcode = daemon.daemonize()
>
> # This would run in daemon mode; output is not visible
> if retcode == yapdi.OPERATION_SUCCESSFUL:
> print('Hello Daemon')
> ```