# sending trigger to my python script

Tags: python, linux, ipc, udev

I have a long running python script that I would like to be called via a `udev` rule. The script should run unattended, in the background if you like. The udev `RUN` is not suitable for long running commands which is getting in my way - my script gets killed after a wile.So I cannot call my script directly via udev.

I tried to disowning it by calling it in udev RUN via a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/path/to/pythonscript.py & disown
```

This still got killed.

Now I was thinking to turn my script into a daemon, e.g. using pythons [`daemon`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) module. Now "all" I need to do is put a short command in my udev `RUN` statement that will send some sort of trigger to my daemon, and things should be fine. What is less clear to me is the best way to implement this communication. I was thinking of adding maybe a jsonrpc service to my daemon, only listening on the loopback device. Is there a simpler or better way to achive what I want?

**EDIT**
Thanks to the below comments I came up with the following solution. Main "daemon":

```
import signal, time
import auto_copy

SIGNAL_RECEIVED = False

def run_daemon():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, signal_handler)
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        global SIGNAL_RECEIVED
        if SIGNAL_RECEIVED:
            auto_copy.auto_copy()
            SIGNAL_RECEIVED = False

def signal_handler(dump1, dump2):
    global SIGNAL_RECEIVED
    SIGNAL_RECEIVED = True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    auto_copy.setup_logging()
    run_daemon()
```

This gets started via systemd, the unit file beeing

```
[Unitt]
Description=Start auto_copy.py script

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/isaac/bin/auto_copy_daemon.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then there is a udev rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sr0", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/home/isaac/bin/send_siguser1.sh"
```

and finally the script that sends the signal:

```
#!/bin/bash
kill -SIGUSR1 $(ps -elf |grep auto_copy_daemon.py |awk '/python/ {print $4}')
```

If anyone is interested, the project is on [github](https://github.com/shoubamzlibap/small_projects/tree/master/auto_copy).

Comment: Do u want your script to run in the background?

Comment: How did you implement "disowning"?

Comment: yes, it should be triggered via udev, on a headless server.

Comment: is sending signal considered as option?

Comment: I guess sending a signal is an option - what kind of signal would be best?

Comment: @Robᵩ question updated with regard to disowning

Comment: possibly a duplicate of:

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975624/how-to-run-a-python-script-in-the-background-even-after-i-logout-ssh)? short answer was use nohup.

Comment: `SIGUSR1` is a good choice.

Comment: @Isaac, for non-standard purposes it's better to use SIGUSR1 or SIGUSR2 to not confuse using a standard signals which are designed for other purposes.