# How can i run a script.py in background?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, daemon

I have the following code:

```
import os
import time

def temp_core():
    temp = os.popen("vcgencmd measure_temp").readline()
    return(temp.replace("temp=",""))

while(True):
    Temp = temp_core()
    if Temp > 70:
        print("Horny!")
    time.sleep(5)
```

I need to run this script (python3) on my raspberry pi3 (debian) in background, (like Daemon o Service) for let me know when my core be on fire!

Comment: If you ran that as a daemon - where would you expect to see `Horny!`?  Just open a terminal and run it ...

Comment: I will replace "print("Horny")" for another command line (Dont worry, its a example). I need to know how could i run this script like a Daemon or Service. ;)

Comment: Again - if it's daemonised, where do you expect to see the output, independent of WHAT you output?

Comment: ok @tink, i want to look "Horny!" in my terminal.

Comment: *sigh* ... so you **don't** want it in the background, then?

Comment: Could i receive this warning in my terminal while the script be run in background?

Comment: @tink; when my core be hot, i run a "send email method". I am excluded this part for my script for make it most single.

Comment: check nohup: if your on *nix [Unix, Linux] there might be some Win equivalent or WSL2 or ... here`s a related q&a:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975624/how-to-run-a-python-script-in-the-background-even-after-i-logout-ssh