# Unable to deploy python script , upon closing terminal script stops running

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, deployment

I have a python script that need to run for 10 days with out any disturbance , new to python is there a way i can run the script , and script should not stop if we close terminal. going to deploy EC2 Ubuntu instance amazon - also my local machine . Please let me know how can i accomplish this task in case of modification needed in the program may need restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`nohup`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup).

And if you retroactively want to exit a shell already running the process you can [`disown`](https://serverfault.com/a/24431/511536) the running process.

You might also use [`screen`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) to run the process in a shell to which you can return.

Comment: @fabianegli- is there any documentation available - how to use nohup

Comment: You can type `man nohup` in the console/terminal/command line to read the manual (press `q` to exit the manual, `space` to scroll down and `b` to scroll up). There is also a simple example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2975645/6018688)