# Efficient Python Daemon

Tags: python, daemon

I was curious how you can run a python script in the background, repeating a task every 60 seconds. I know you can put something in the background using &, is that effeictive for this case?

I was thinking of doing a loop, having it wait 60s and loading it again, but something feels off about that.

Comment: It depends what you want. If you want to schedule a task to repeat every so often, take a look at cron.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think your idea is pretty much exactly what you want. For example:

```
import time

def do_something():
    with open("/tmp/current_time.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write("The time is now " + time.ctime())

def run():
    while True:
        time.sleep(60)
        do_something()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

The call to `time.sleep(60)` will put your program to sleep for 60 seconds. When that time is up, the OS will wake up your program and run the `do_something()` function, then put it back to sleep. While your program is sleeping, it is doing nothing very efficiently. This is a general pattern for writing background services.

To actually run this from the command line, you can use &:

```
$ python background_test.py &
```

When doing this, any output from the script will go to the same terminal as the one you started it from. You can redirect output to avoid this:

```
$ python background_test.py >stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt &
```

Comment: Thanks man, this is exactly what I was looking for. The bits and pieces of programming I know come from Javascript and trying to do anything on a timer there turned into a nightmare!

Comment: You may also want to look at nohup (e.g. `nohup python background_test.py`) assuming you want the daemon to keep running after you log out)

Comment: There is an easier way to do this using `python-daemon` which is the "standard daemon process library": http://stackoverflow.com/a/8375012/462302

Comment: @user2452250: Please see the question [What does `if __name__ == “__main__”:` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Answer (score 110):

Rather than writing your own daemon, use [python-daemon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon) instead! [python-daemon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon) implements the well-behaved daemon specification of [PEP 3143](http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143), "Standard daemon process library".

I have included example code based on the accepted answer to this question, and even though the code looks almost identical, it has an important fundamental difference. Without [python-daemon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon) you would have to use `&` to put your process in the background and `nohup` and to keep your process from getting killed when you exit your shell. Instead this will automatically detach from your terminal when you run the program.

For example:

```
import daemon
import time

def do_something():
    while True:
        with open("/tmp/current_time.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write("The time is now " + time.ctime())
        time.sleep(5)

def run():
    with daemon.DaemonContext():
        do_something()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

To actually run it:

```
python background_test.py
```

And note the absence of `&` here.

Also, [this other stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473620/how-do-you-create-a-daemon-in-python) explains in detail the many benefits of using [python-daemon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon).

Comment: You would be surprised, but PEP author and library author is the same person. So yes, library very well implement that PEP :)

Comment: You say "this other stackoverflow answer" but link to a question, not an answer. The selected answer to the question you link to does not use (at the time of this comment) python-daemon. Maybe you meant https://stackoverflow.com/a/688448/117471 ?

Answer (score 8):

Using & in the shell is probably the dead simplest way as Greg described.

If you really want to create a powerful Daemon though, you will need to look into the os.fork() command.

The example from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(operating_system)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, time

def createDaemon():
  """ 
      This function create a service/Daemon that will execute a det. task
  """

  try:
    # Store the Fork PID
    pid = os.fork()

    if pid > 0:
      print 'PID: %d' % pid
      os._exit(0)

  except OSError, error:
    print 'Unable to fork. Error: %d (%s)' % (error.errno, error.strerror)
    os._exit(1)

  doTask()

def doTask():
  """ 
      This function create a task that will be a daemon
  """

  # Open the file in write mode
  file = open('/tmp/tarefa.log', 'w')

  # Start the write
  while True:
    print >> file, time.ctime()
    file.flush()
    time.sleep(2)

  # Close the file
  file.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':

  # Create the Daemon
  createDaemon()
```

And then you could put whatever task you needed inside the `doTask()` block.

You wouldn't need to launch this using &, and it would allow you to customize the execution a little further.