# Monitoring a python script on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have a series of Python producers that are pulling in data from various sources. At the moment, I am starting each one manually via terminal, but I need to figure a more robust system. I'd like to create a local browser based dashboard that I can use to start / stop and monitor each of the Python processes.

So, using Ubuntu, how would I go about starting a python script as a system process as opposed to having to have a terminal window for each one?

Also, in order to monitor the status of each producer, I was planning on using a broker such as rabbitmq or reddis to log any changes / errors that I can monitor via the web dashboard. The problem I have is that if a producer crashes for whatever reason, it will still show as 'running' on the dashboard. Should I create some kind of supervisor that is responsible for spawning and monitoring each individual producer?

I'd appreciate any suggestions as to how I can achieve this.

Comment: Looks like you need a Web Application. Take a look at Django, then you could put all your scripts into the Django project and control them via browser. (or not?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want to create Daemons with Python. Please refer to the following answer to understand how to write them in Python: [How do you create a daemon in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473620/how-do-you-create-a-daemon-in-python)

For the "Monitoring" thing you can implement something that will check if the PID written in the PID File is alive, that you can do by using [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) as 'rpInt' suggested.