# python-daemon context fails to start when a stale PID file is present

Tags: python, daemon, python-daemon

I'm using python-daemon, and having the problem that when I `kill -9` a process, it leaves a pidfile behind (ok) and the next time I run my program it doesn't work unless I have already removed the pidfile by hand (not ok).

I catch all exceptions in order that `context.close()` is called before terminating -- when this happens (e.g. on a `kill`) the /var/run/mydaemon.pid* files are removed and a subsequent daemon run succeeds.  However, when using SIGKILL (`kill -9`), I don't have the chance to call `context.close()`, and the /var/run files remain.  In this instance, the next time I run my program it does not start successfully -- the original process returns, but the daemonized process blocks at `context.open()`.

It seems like python-daemon ought to be noticing that there is a pidfile for a process that no longer exists, and clearing it out, but that isn't happening.  Am I supposed to be doing this by hand?

Note: I'm not using `with` because this code runs on Python 2.4

```
from daemon import DaemonContext
from daemon.pidlockfile import PIDLockFile

context = DaemonContext(pidfile = PIDLockFile("/var/run/mydaemon.pid"))
context.open()

try:
    retry_main_loop()
except Exception, e:
    pass
context.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running linux, and process level locks are acceptable, read on.

We try to acquire the lock. If it fails, check if the lock is acquired by a running process. If no, break the lock and continue.

```
from lockfile.pidlockfile import PIDLockFile
from lockfile import AlreadyLocked

pidfile = PIDLockFile("/var/run/mydaemon.pid", timeout=-1)
try:
    pidfile.acquire()
except AlreadyLocked:
    try:
        os.kill(pidfile.read_pid(), 0)
        print 'Process already running!'
        exit(1)
    except OSError:  #No process with locked PID
        pidfile.break_lock()

#pidfile can now be used to create DaemonContext
```

Edit: Looks like PIDLockFile is available only on lockfile >= 0.9

Comment: It was two years ago so my memory is hazy, but yeah, I think this is how I did it (what I meant by "doing this by hand" referenced in the question).  Marking as answer because why not.

Answer (score 1):

With the script provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473620/how-do-you-create-a-daemon-in-python/9047339#9047339)
the pid file remains on kill -9 as you say, but the script also cleans up properly on a restart.