# Python: Running Daemon Processes in Windows7

Tags: python, windows

I had a program that Scraped certain data from certain Web-Pages, and when the Web-Pages changed, acted accordingly.

How would one set up the program so it continues to run in the background?

I don't need *any* specifics

I'm just really confused on this concept and would appreciate whatever help anybody has to offer.

Comment: In today's multitasking systems, there's very little difference between "foreground" and "background", programs just run. What system are you using? (It matters.)

Comment: Take a Look at the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843903/how-to-start-daemon-process-from-python-on-windows/12844523#12844523)

Answer (score 10):

`start path-to-pythonw.exe your-code.py`

pythonw means without console.

start means start on background.

if your python is installed system-wide, you can probably `start your-code.pyw`

`.pyw` is associated with `pythonw.exe`

remember you cannot use print (to stdout) in this case.

Comment: I have ran into problems that every print threw an exception. Another developer left prints all over the place ans stdout being closed/disconnected made python throw.

Comment: This opens up another commandline window in windows8.1, it is not working in the background :/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to just start your process and have it background itself and do a few more typical things that "daemon" processes do in Unix, look here: [How do you create a daemon in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473620/how-do-you-create-a-daemon-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of "background" in Windows. But the UNIX shell concept of a background process can be reasonably emulated by running your Python script as a Windows service. There are a couple of suggestions in this question: [Is it possible to run a Python script as a service in Windows? If possible, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/can-i-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows-how)

For casual use, I suggest that you learn how to use `srvany` from the second answer.

Answer (score -1):

You simply need to leave your program running! Please google "python daemon" and see how to implement a persistent background process in Python.

Now, you cannot know when a website changes unless you poll it. If the website is well designed, the page you are trying to poll will have a "Last-Modified" header, you can make a "HEAD" request every so often (be nice: don't poll like crazy) and act when Last-Modified is >= than the one on record. If the site is not well designed, it will not have a reliable Last-Modified or ETAG header, in that case you will have to parse manually and check for changes yourself.

Cheers.