# How to package a Python daemon with setuptools

Tags: python, linux, daemon, setuptools, python-daemon

How do you package a Python app with setuptools so that when it's installed (e.g. via setup.py or pip), it places a daemon script in the appropriate location, starts it, and marks it to automatically start at boot time?

In my case, my code only works with Linux, so I only care about installing the daemon in Linux environments (specifically Ubuntu).

I've found [several](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473620/how-do-you-create-a-daemon-in-python) [describing](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/278731/) how to easily create Python daemons, but I can't seem to find anything describing how you'd install them in a production environment so that they'd be treated as any other normal daemon or service.

I know Ubuntu and some other distros keep their daemons in /etc/init.d, and I know how to use setuptools to copy files to specific locations on the filesystem, so would it be safe to copy or symlink my script to /etc/init.d and then run chkconfig to set it's runtime, or is there a more safe distribution-neutral way of installing daemons?

Answer (score 3):

This would be better handled by creating an appropriate package for the distro (in the case of Ubuntu, a .deb) since you can't guarantee the location of the startup scripts across distros.  For example, arch linux uses /etc/rc.d/.  Also, copying to locations like that will require root access (which I don't believe is necessarily required to install python packages) and may not be easily reversible when uninstalling.

I would suggest that you  create a normal setupttools installation and then package it into a deb with a link to /etc/init.d.

Comment: Interesting. Although I've *always* had to `sudo` to install Python packages, so I don't think being root is an issue.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think that, in python3 at least, you can install to a user-specific location (e.g. ~/.python or something)

Comment: You can always use virtualenv and install package wherever you want

Comment: @Dikei: That might be what I'm thinking of.

Comment: How would you actually go about doing this?