# Clean shutdown of a Python script

Tags: python, bash, process, exit, kill

I have a threaded server written in Python that I start using the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

base_path="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

public_dns=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname)
echo $public_dns > "$base_path/client/address"

cd "$base_path/server"
python "server.py" &
echo $! > "$base_path/server_pid"
echo "Server running"
```

I echo the PID to a file so that I can shutdown a server using another shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

base_path="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

kill -9 `cat "$base_path/server_pid"`
rm "$base_path/server_pid"
rm "$base_path/client/address"
```

I know, however, that this is a bad approach considering the server has many threads that have I/O into network and hdd... So what I would like to do is have the second script somehow interact with the server and tell it to start a shutdown sequence which would cleanly close all the threads, close & archive logs etc.

Now I know about [atexit](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html) and I tested it this way:

```
import atexit
def byebye(o):
    o.write('stop')
    o.flush()
    o.close()

o = open('log','w')
o.write('start')
o.flush()

atexit.register(byebye, o)

while True:
    pass
```

But when I `kill -9` the process, `byebye()` is not fired. Should I use a command other than  the [almighty `kill -9`](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fow7iUaKrq4)? How would I go about shutting down the process?

Comment: What about sockets? You could either write to a local file socket or use a network socket (specific port maybe and only communicated via localhost). There you could tell it to shut down. Kill seems to be a bit harsh...

Comment: As long as you don't have any `try/except KeyboardInterrupt` clauses, you could use `kill -2` as that will send SIGINT.  A more clean solution would be to register a signal handler in python which call `sys.exit` -- Although I'm not sure how that would work since you're in a threaded environment...

Comment: I have thought about just writing the word 'stop' to a file which would be constantly monitored by the server, but thats another thread to launch and I thought that maybe there is a more elegant way to do this in Python

Comment: The `cd` is unnecessary; `base_path=$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")`

Comment: @mgilson: after some tests I think your approach is best, post it as answer so that I may accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not particularly used to programming with threads, but rather than sending `kill -9` (which corresponds to `SIGKILL`), you could send `SIGINT` or some other user defined signal.  `SIGINT` (`kill -2` on my system) is nice because that one is already understood by python.  (When python catches that signal, it raises a `KeyboardInterrupt`), but any signal will work.  You just need to register a signal handler that exits your program cleanly.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that your are trying to implement a daemon.
There is various references about daemon implementations in python :

Previous stackoverlow question :
[How do you create a daemon in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473620/how-do-you-create-a-daemon-in-python)

PEP regarding daemon :
http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/

python module implementing PEP3143 :
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/

Note that the PEP is a draft.

More about daemons : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29

Typically, daemon are started, stopped and restarted as :

```
mydaemon start
mydaemon stop
mydaemon restart
```

So you dont need to know the PID or anything else to stop it.

Comment: The server is based on the SocketServer (http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html) which already runs as a daemon (by `server_thread.daemon = True`), so wrapping my script to be a daemon which starts a daemon seems a bit unnecessary?

Comment: I am not an expert in daemon and networking application but it seems that the functionality provided by this server_thread.daemon option is not the same as the one provided by the python-daemon module. In particular, the convenient command-line interface provided by python-daemon is not included in the SocketServer module.

Answer (score 1):

`kill 9` is atomic powered - you don't get to clean up after yourself. A better approach would be to use a different, gentler, signal (`HUP` is commonly used to signal a server process that it is time to shut down, for example), and teach your python code how to handle it gracefully.

The [signal module documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.8/library/signal.html) should get you started.