# SIGTERM signal not received by python on shutdown command

Tags: python, signals, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have been programming using python for the raspberryPi for several months now and I am trying to make my scripts "well behaved" and wrap up (close files and make sure no writes to SD are being perfomed) upon reception of SIGTERM.

Following advice on SO ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544553/clean-shutdown-of-a-python-script?rq=1), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148888/python-trap-all-signals)) I am able to handle SIGTERM if I kill the process manually (i.e. **kill {process number}**) but if I send the shutdown command (i.e. **shutdown -t 30 now**) my handler never gets called.

I also tried registering for all signals and checking the signal being send on the shutdown event but I am not getting any.

Here's simple example code:

```
import time
import signal
import sys


def myHandler(signum, frame):
    print "Signal #, ", signum
    sys.exit()

for i in [x for x in dir(signal) if x.startswith("SIG")]:
    try:
        signum = getattr(signal, i)
        signal.signal(signum, myHandler)
        print "Handler added for {}".format(i)
    except RuntimeError,m:
        print "Skipping %s"%i
    except ValueError:
        break
while True:
    print "goo"
    time.sleep(1)
```

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated .. =)

Comment: it's possible that on `shutdown` you get `SIGTERM`, but the script isn't able to output to the screen.  Append to a log file, then check the log when the machine comes back.

Comment: Good point. I will try it and report my findings

Comment: @shavenwarthog: When I try the `shutdown` command with `-t` (as far as I understand is the time between `SIGTERM` and `SIGKILL`) I can configure a reasonable amount of time to see the output to the screen. Anyway is a valid point.

Answer (score 0):

this code works for me on the raspberry pi, i can see the correct output in the file output.log after the restart:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=WARNING,
                    filename='output.log',
                    format='%(message)s')   
def quit():
    #cleaning code here
    logging.warning('exit')
    sys.exit(0)

def handler(signum=None, frame=None):
    quit()

for sig in [signal.SIGTERM, signal.SIGHUP, signal.SIGQUIT, signal.SIGKILL]:
    signal.signal(sig, handler)

def restart():
    command = '/sbin/shutdown -r now'
    process = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = process.communicate()[0]
    logging.warning('%s'%output)

restart()
```

maybe your terminal handles the signal before the python script does, so you can't actually see anything. Try to see the output in a file (with the logging module or the way as you like).