# Exit a Python process not kill it (via ssh)

Tags: python

I am starting my script locally via:

```
sudo python run.py remote
```

This script happens to also open a subprocess (if that matters)

```
webcam = subprocess.Popen('avconv -f video4linux2 -s 320x240 -r 20 -i /dev/video0 -an -metadata title="OfficeBot" -f flv rtmp://6f7528a4.fme.bambuser.com/b-fme/xxx', shell = True)
```

I want to know how to terminate this script when I SSH in.

I understand I can do:

```
sudo pkill -f "python run.py remote"
```

or use:

```
ps -f -C python
```

to find the process ID and kill it that way.

However none of these gracefully kill the process, I want to able to trigger the equilivent of CTRL/CMD C to register an exit command (I do lots of things on shutdown that aren't triggered when the process is simply killed).

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use "signals" for it:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html

Example:

```
import signal, os

def handler(signum, frame):
    print 'Signal handler called with signal', signum

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
#do your stuff
```

then in terminal:

```
kill -INT $PID
```

or ctrl+c if your script is active in current shell

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal

also this might be useful:

[How do you create a daemon in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473620/how-do-you-create-a-daemon-in-python)

Comment: This works great for the main process, however my subprocess continues to output:


def killme(signum, frame):
        webcam.kill()
        sys.exit()

Answer (score 2):

You can use [signals](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal#module-signal) for communicating with your process. If you want to emulate <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> the signal is SIGINT (which you can raise by `kill -INT` and process id. You can also modify the behavior for `SIGTERM` which would make your program shut down cleanly under a broader range of circumstances.