# How do I turn my python program into a service on uBuntu?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, service

I have a piece of software made in python I am running on a uBuntu instance. But I want to package it so that the user can see it as a service.

for example, he can do "/etc/init.d/myPythonProgram restart" to restart. Just like any other service.

Answer (score 1):

You want to search for how to create a 'daemon' with python. So...

[How do you create a daemon in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473620/how-do-you-create-a-daemon-in-python)

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/daemonize

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a script in /etc/init.d/ ,in this script ,you need to define how to start and stop the software.here is an example:

```
case "$1" in
    start)
        start_software
        ;;
    stop)
        stop_software
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 start|stop" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
exit 0
```