# Accessing Running Python program from another Python program

Tags: python

I have the following program running

```
collector.py

data=0
while True:
    #collects data
     data=data+1
```

I have another program cool.py which wants to access the current data value. How can I do this?

Ultimately, something like:

cool.py

```
getData()
```

*An Idea would be to use a global variable for data?

Comment: Do you want a daemon? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473620/how-do-you-create-a-daemon-in-python

Comment: The simplest way is to write the data to a file every minute with a timestamp on the filename.
Then your other file could just look for new files every minute & delete them once processed.

Comment: `global` won't help:  each process has its own globals.  You need some form of inter-process communication, and *both* programs have to *cooperate* to make this happen.  Possibilities include sockets, pipes, the `multiprocessing` module, or something as simple as one program periodically writing data to a file and the the other program reading that file.

Comment: I actually have a way of combining the programs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use memory mapping. 
http://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html

For example you open a file in tmp directore, next u mapping this file to memory in both program and write u data to this file.

Comment: interesting! ill have a peek

Comment: Yes. Memory mapping use your ram to access in this file. I use memory mapping in C++ program, but in python shall be also very efficent. If you want i can gave you example code but in C.

Comment: Interesting! Right now I am using sockets to communicate between programs. Is it more efficient that?