# How to use Daemon that has a while loop?

Tags: python

I am new with Daemons and I was wondering how can I make my main script a daemon?

I have my main script which I wish to make a Daemon and run in the background:

```
 main.py

     def requestData(information):
         return currently_crunched_data()

     while True:
          crunchData()
```

I would like to be able to use the requestData function to this daemon while the loop is running. I am not too familiar with Daemons or how to convert my script into one.

However I am guessing I would have to make two threads, one for my cruncData loop and one for the Daemon request receiever since the Daemon has its own loop (daemon.requestLoop()).

I am currently looking into Pyro to do this. Does anyone know how I can ultimately make a background running while loop have the ability to receive requests from other processes (like a Daemon I suppose) ?

Comment: I recommend using supervisord - it avoids the need to deal with daemon issues.

Comment: There are two separate questions here. First, there's "how do I do two things at one", and yes, using a background thread is an obvious way to do it, and will work. Then, there's "how do I write a daemon in Python", and that's a dup. So, I'm going to ignore the second one.

Comment: Sorry I already know how to write a Daemon in Python: http://doc.uh.cz/Python/Pyro-3.1/8-example.html

The problem is that Daemon itself is a while loop and my process is a while loop.

Comment: Yes I am using Linux but hopefully there is a universal solution

Comment: @KingofGames: Good, then I've ignored the right part and answered (I hope) the right part. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are already a number of questions on creating a daemon in Python, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473620/how-do-you-create-a-daemon-in-python/688448#688448), which answer that part nicely.

So, how do you have your daemon do background work?

As you suspected, threads are an obvious answer. But there are three possible complexities.

---

First, there's shutdown. If you're lucky, your `crunchData` function can be summarily killed at any time with no corrupted data or (too-significant) lost work. In that case:

```
def worker():
    while True:
        crunchData()

# ... somewhere in the daemon startup code ...
t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
t.daemon = True
t.start()
```

Notice that `t.daemon`. A ["daemon thread"](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects) has nothing to do with your program being a daemon; it means that you can just quit the main process, and it will be summarily killed.

But what if `crunchData` can't be killed? Then you'll need to do something like this:

```
quitflag = False
quitlock = threading.Lock()

def worker():
    while True:
        with quitlock:
            if quitflag:
                return
        crunchData()

# ... somewhere in the daemon startup code ...
t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
t.start()

# ... somewhere in the daemon shutdown code ...
with quitlock:
    quitflag = True
t.join()
```

I'm assuming each iteration of `crunchData` doesn't take that long. If it does, you may need to check `quitFlag` periodically within the function itself.

---

Meanwhile, you want your request handler to access some data that the background thread is producing. You'll need some kind of synchronization there as well.

The obvious thing is to just use another `Lock`. But there's a good chance that `crunchData` is writing to its data frequently. If it holds the lock for 10 seconds at a time, the request handler may block for 10 seconds. But if it grabs and releases the lock a million times, that could take longer than the actual work.

One alternative is to double-buffer your data: Have `crunchData` write into a new copy, then, when it's done, briefly grab the lock and set `currentData = newData`.

Depending on your use case, a `Queue`, a file, or something else might be even simpler.

---

Finally, `crunchData` is presumably doing a lot of CPU work. You need to make sure that the request handler does very little CPU work, or each request will slow things down quite a bit as the two threads fight over the GIL. Usually this is no problem. If it is, use a `multiprocessing.Process` instead of a `Thread` (which makes sharing or passing the data between the two processes slightly more complicated, but still not too bad).