# How to make RabbitMQ worker listening continuously ?

Tags: php, cron, rabbitmq, daemon

I am implementing rabbitMQ with more than 3 workers processing. To test it, I need to execute worker file each time, but I don't want that.

I want my worker script to listen all request continuously without manually executing worker file. Many people suggested CRON but I don't want because if previous run hasn't finished then overlap can cause serious issues.

Is there any way to run my worker script continuously in background?

Answer (score 6):

What you actually want is to run your worker as a [daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)). The basic idea is to run your task in a loop without any user interaction and write the output into a log file.

This is a complex task and depending on the programming language of your choice there might be a library that will handle that for you.

- PHP: [PHP-Daemon](https://github.com/shaneharter/PHP-Daemon)
- Ruby: [Ruby-Daemons](https://github.com/thuehlinger/daemons)
- Python: [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473620/how-do-you-create-a-daemon-in-python)
- Java: [Apache Commons daemon](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/)

Another useful approach specific to RabbitMQ is to run your worker code as command line program with the [RabbitMQ-cli-consumer](https://github.com/ricbra/rabbitmq-cli-consumer). This approach will work for any programming language with cli support. Especially for script languages with stability issues like PHP this will be the favorable way to go.

Comment: RabbitMQ-cli-consumer is deprecated. Fortunately, there is an official fork that is still alive: https://github.com/corvus-ch/rabbitmq-cli-consumer