# How can I write a non-stop crawler with python and run it on a server?

Tags: python, ubuntu, service, web-scraping

I want to write a **scraper** with python that crawl some urls and scrape and save datas.
I know how can I write it as a simple program. I'm looking for a way to deploy it on my virtual server (running ubuntu) as a service to make it non-stop crawling.
Could any one tell me How can I do this?

Comment: So which part do you need help on? Letting it run for a long time? Writing a crawler? Using python with Linux?

Comment: Letting it run for a long time :) @SleepDeprivedBulbasaur

Comment: Use scrapy to build your own crawler.  Don't ever let the queue of URLs that it's scraping go empty.   http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html

Comment: How about `while True: scrape()`? That will run for a long time.

Comment: @BardiaHeydari you want to look into daemonizing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is daemonize the process.  [This will be helpful in creating a daemon.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473620/how-do-you-create-a-daemon-in-python)

Daemonizing the process will allow it to run in background mode, so as long as the server is running (even if a user isn't logged in) it will continue running.

Here is an example daemon that writes the time to a file.

```
import daemon
import time

def do_something():
    while True:
        with open("/tmp/current_time.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write("The time is now " + time.ctime())
        time.sleep(5)

def run():
    with daemon.DaemonContext():
        do_something()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```