# Python 3.3.4: python-daemon-3K ; How to use runner

Tags: python, daemon, python-daemon

Struggling to try and get a python daemon to work using Python 3.3.4. Im using the latest version of the python-daemon-3K from PyPi i.e. 1.5.8

Starting point is the following code found [How do you create a daemon in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473620/how-do-you-create-a-daemon-in-python.This) code i believe is 2.x Python.

```
import time
from daemon import runner

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.stdin_path = '/dev/null'
        self.stdout_path = '/dev/tty'
        self.stderr_path = '/dev/tty'
        self.pidfile_path =  '/tmp/foo.pid'
        self.pidfile_timeout = 5
    def run(self):
        while True:
            print("Howdy!  Gig'em!  Whoop!")
            time.sleep(10)

app = App()
daemon_runner = runner.DaemonRunner(app)
daemon_runner.do_action()
```

Attempting to run this i get the following error.

> python mydaemon.py start
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "mydaemon.py", line 60, in 
>           daemon_runner = runner.DaemonRunner(app)
>         File "/depot/Python-3.3.4/lib/python3.3/site-packages/python_daemon_3K-1.5.8-py3.3.egg/daemon/runner.py", line 89, in **init**
>           app.stderr_path, 'w+', buffering=0)
>     ValueError: can't have unbuffered text I/O

Any pointer how to translate to work with Python 3.3.4 or a good example of using the runner in python-daemon-3K

Thanks
derek

Answer (score 5):

To make the code run in python3 you need to make a change in the `DaemonRunner` class, you cannot have unbuffered text IO but you can have unbuffered bytes IO so changing the mode to`'wb+'` will work:

```
class DaemonRunner(object):

        self.parse_args()
        self.app = app
        self.daemon_context = DaemonContext()
        self.daemon_context.stdin = open(app.stdin_path, 'r') 
        # for linux /dev/tty must be opened without buffering and with b
        self.daemon_context.stdout = open(app.stdout_path, 'wb+',buffering=0)
        # w+ -> wb+
        self.daemon_context.stderr = open(
            app.stderr_path, 'wb+', buffering=0)
```

Comment: I am seeing the warnings.warn(
        "The ‘runner’ module is not a supported API for this library.",
        DeprecationWarning) is DaemonRunner is deprecated? any alternative API are there

Answer (score 0):

To make the code run in python3 you need to make a change in the `DaemonRunner` class

```
class DaemonRunner(object):
    self.parse_args()
    self.app = app
    self.daemon_context = DaemonContext()
    self.daemon_context.stdin = open(app.stdin_path, 'r') 
    self.daemon_context.stdout = open(app.stdout_path, 'w+')
    self.daemon_context.stderr = open(app.stderr_path, 'w+')
```

Comment: I am seeing the warnings.warn(
        "The ‘runner’ module is not a supported API for this library.",
        DeprecationWarning) is DaemonRunner is deprecated? any alternative API are there