# Python's daemon PPID not equal to 1

Tags: python, linux, pid, systemd, python-daemon

Creating daemons in Linux is [quite complex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954432/creating-a-daemon-in-linux/38818264#38818264) issue, but it's very well documented in [`daemon(7) manual`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/daemon.html). Thankfully there is [`python-daemon`](https://pagure.io/python-daemon) module for Python 2 and 3 that implement [PEP3143](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/), so I'm using it.

Here comes the question: when I was playing with [`python-daemon`](https://pagure.io/python-daemon) module I was surprised that daemon's [PPID](https://delightlylinux.wordpress.com/2012/06/25/what-is-pid-and-ppid/) is **not** [`1`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159964/how-to-check-whether-a-process-is-daemon-or-not). Why?

---

Simple example:

```
import daemon
import time
import os

with open('/tmp/test.log', 'w') as logfile:
    c = daemon.DaemonContext(stdout=logfile)
    with c:
        print('In daemon...')
        for i in range(10):
            print('My PID is {}, PPID is {}'.format(os.getpid(), os.getppid()))
            time.sleep(2)
```

Content of `test.log` after 20 seconds from starting the above script (I recommend [`tail -f /tmp/test.log`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_(Unix))):

```
In daemon...
My PID is 31397, PPID is 1736
My PID is 31397, PPID is 1736
My PID is 31397, PPID is 1736
My PID is 31397, PPID is 1736
My PID is 31397, PPID is 1736
My PID is 31397, PPID is 1736
My PID is 31397, PPID is 1736
My PID is 31397, PPID is 1736
My PID is 31397, PPID is 1736
My PID is 31397, PPID is 1736
```

It turned out that process with PID `1736` is [`/lib/systemd/systemd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd):

```
patryk@mycomp:/tmp$ ps -fq 1736
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
patryk    1736     1  0 kwi12 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
```

Recently I was implementing daemons in [`C`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) (on the same machine with [`systemd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) installed) and [AFAIR](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/AFAIR) all daemons had `PPID = 1`. All manuals I came across mention that daemon's [PPID](https://delightlylinux.wordpress.com/2012/06/25/what-is-pid-and-ppid/) is always [`1`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159964/how-to-check-whether-a-process-is-daemon-or-not).

Does [`systemd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) changed it? Does [`systemd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) process [`awaits`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) for all processes – including daemons? Is it daemon's correct behavior?

---

Related questions:

- [How do you create a daemon in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473620/how-do-you-create-a-daemon-in-python)
- [How do I set up a daemon with python-daemon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106221/how-do-i-set-up-a-daemon-with-python-daemon)
- [How to make a Python script run like a service or daemon in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603109/how-to-make-a-python-script-run-like-a-service-or-daemon-in-linux)
- [Python 3.3.4: python-daemon-3K ; How to use runner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506088/python-3-3-4-python-daemon-3k-how-to-use-runner)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: It doesn't matter.

The important thing is that all daemons have a parent process like `init` that will reap children when they die, by calling `wait()`. Otherwise the process will become a *zombie* when it exits.

There's nothing particularly special about having a parent PID of 1. The manual page you linked to says this process is PID 1 for old, SysV-style daemons, but doesn't say so for new SystemD-style daemons. `init` always runs as PID 1, and traditionally it was the parent of daemons. But it doesn't *need* to be so.

[`systemd --user`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User) manages *user* services. Thus, it makes sense why this process becomes your daemon's parent process when you run it (as a user).

One must be careful when reading documentation about *nix, a platform that's been around for decades. Things change and manuals become obsolete, or can be interpreted in the wrong context. SystemD brings major change to *a lot* of things about the Linux platform.

Comment: It is also incidental that `init` gets PID 1: because it is the first user-space process that the kernel runs, and it never exits while the system is online. The PID 1 is not special for any other reason; similarly, the PID of `systemd` is not special.

Answer (score 0):

> All manuals I came across mention that daemon's PPID is always 1.

Those manuals are incorrect; a daemon gets whatever parent is going to manage detached processes.

If that *happens to be* the `init` process, and if `init` *happens to have* PID 1, then that'll be the daemon's PPID; but both of those are arbitrary, not definitional. Manuals should not imply otherwise.

The `init` process only typically gets PID 1 (and apparently there are no exceptions to this) because, arbitrarily, the first user-space process gets assigned PID 1, and that happens to be `init`, which then never exits while the host is online. There's nothing special about PID 1 otherwise.

The `systemd` process will, likewise, get whatever arbitrary PID is assigned for the timing of its start-up.

Other process managers, such as `runit`, will similarly get an arbitrary PID when they start up.

Can you post a bug report to those manuals that are getting it wrong?

Comment: I don't think it's quite as arbitrary as you say. The Linux kernel mentions in several places that `init` is PID 1: *"We need to spawn init first so that it obtains pid 1"* ([`init/main.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.20/init/main.c#L405)), *"init really needs pid 1"* ([`kernel/pid.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.20/kernel/pid.c#L182)), *"there is always at least one task in the system (init, pid == 1)"* ([`kernel/cgroup/cgroup.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.20/kernel/cgroup/cgroup.c#L1386)).