# How to start threads in python that will continue when the parent process is exited?

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, daemon, scheduler

I'm trying to write a scheduler script for slurm jobs in python.

Basically, I have a script contained in a function,let's call it `job_array_scheduler()`, that contains a `time.sleep()` loop. This is expected to run for a day or more. I want to be able to start this function off as a separate thread from inside python, such that I can then exit the session and this thing will keep running.

I tried doing it like so:

```
import threading
scheduler_thread = threading.Thread(target=job_array_scheduler, args=args, daemon=True)
scheduler_thread.start()
```

but this exits when I exit the python session (i.e just with `exit`).

How to I get around this, to keep the above thread alive so I can exit the python session or even log my user off?

The only way I can think of is writing *another* script to wrap around the above, so I can run it in the background from the shell doing something like `python wrapper_script.py &` but I would prefer to avoid that as I would have to write a separate outer script for each such job I want to do.

Comment: Use processes with `multiprocessing` instead of threads (which, in python, don't work as you expect anyway thanks to the GIL)

Answer (score 0):

Don't exit the process (threads are part of the process and cannot outlive it).  What you want is to [daemonize (or detach)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473620/how-do-you-create-a-daemon-in-python) the process.