# My daemon die directly after starting

Tags: python, linux, bash, service, daemon

I have to develop a program with Python3 which executes automatically programs at specific times. I must use a daemon and I can't use external libraries.

That's why I create an install program which configure the daemon (I followed this tutorial https://openclassrooms.com/courses/faire-un-demon-sous-linux).

The file `gobatch` is the program which executes automatically programs.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import os
import sys
import time
import shutil

# Check if script is start with root rights
if os.geteuid() != 0:
    exit('You need to have root privileges to run this script. Use \'sudo ./install.py\'.')

# Title
print('----- ProcessManager install ----- \n')

time.sleep(1)

# Get path of gobatch file
gobatchPath = input("Please enter the path (absolute) where the ProcessManager gobatch program is located: ")

# Check if file exists
try:
    with open(gobatchPath):
        pass
except IOError:
    exit('Error : file does not exists.')

# Copy gobatch file into /usr/bin/
shutil.copy(gobatchPath, '/usr/bin/gobatch')

# Create and fill the automatic launch program
description = 'Deamon that allows you to run cyclicaly at a date or a specific time a program'

fileContent = '#### BEGIN INIT INFO \n' \
              '# Provides:          chillispot et freeradius dans le chroot \n' \
              '# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network \n' \
              '# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs _\n' \
              '# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5 \n' \
              '# Default-Stop:      0 1 6 \n' \
              '# Short-Description: Wireless & LAN Access Point Controller \n' \
              '# Description:       ChilliSpot is an open source captive portal \n' \
              '#                    or wireless LAN access point controller. \n' \
              '### END INIT INFO \n\n\n' \
              'DESC="' + description + '"\n' \
              'DEAMON=/usr/bin/gobatch'

file = open('/etc/init.d/gobatch', 'w')
file.write(fileContent)
file.close()

# Give the rights
os.chmod('/etc/init.d/gobatch', 0o755)

# Save gobatch file to be active
os.system('update-rc.d gobatch defaults')
```

However, when I start the service with : `/etc/init.d/gobatch start` and displaying the status with `service gobatch status` I get

```
gobatch.service - SYSV: ChilliSpot is an open source captive portal
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/gobatch; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
```

Can you tell me if my way is the right method or it exists other solutions?

And do you have any idea why my daemon die directly after starting?

Thank's for help!

**UPDATE**

Currently, my `gobatch` file is not a real program because I prefer create the deamon before.

**gobatch file**

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "it works !"
```

My work is to create the installer of the daemon, not the `gobatch` program. It's another person who must do that. That's why I'm using a minmial content.

**UPDATE 2:**

My new `/etc/init.d/gobatch` :

```
#!/bin/sh
#### BEGIN INIT INFO 
# Provides:          chillispot et freeradius dans le chroot 
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network 
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs _
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5 
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6 
# Short-Description: Wireless & LAN Access Point Controller 
# Description:       ChilliSpot is an open source captive portal 
#                    or wireless LAN access point controller. 
### END INIT INFO 


PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin 
DESC="Deamon that allows you to run cyclicaly at a date or a specific time a program" 
NAME=gobatch 
DEAMON=/usr/sbin/gobatch 
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid 
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/"$NAME" 

. /lib/lsb/init-functions 

case "$1" in 
start) log_daemon_msg "Starting gobatch" 
       start_daemon -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON 
       log_end_msg $? 
       ;; 
stop) log_daemon_msg "Stopping gobatch" 
      killproc -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON 
      RETVAL=$? 
      [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && [ -e "$PIDFILE" ] && rm -f $PIDFILE 
      log_end_msg $RETVAL 
      ;; 
restart) log_daemon_msg "Restarting gobatch" 
         $0 stop 
         $0 start 
         ;; 
esac 
exit 0
```

With this code I get this error :

> gobatch.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /etc/init.d/gobatch: Exec format error

**UPDATE 3:**

The last error into logs file is :

> janv. 08 15:33:07 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: ChilliSpot is an open source captive portal.

I hope after that, my program will works.

Comment: Have you checked the system log files?

Comment: No I don't know where I can see that. Into `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: It seems that the problem is in the `gobatch` program itself, not in the installer.  Thus it would make more sense to post the source of the program instead of the installer.

Comment: @TomášCerha thank's for your answer. I updated my question.

Comment: As for the "Exec format error": I guess you are missing the line #!/bin/bash ath the first line of the /etc/init.d/gobash

Comment: Yes I forgot it... Thank's a lot! I update my question with last error presents on logs file.

Comment: Your init script should use the functions defined in /lib/lsb/init-functions.  Don't know which version you have, but the latest is documented here: http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/iniscrptfunc.html.  I don't see a function named `log_daemon_msg` there.  Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: That's was the problem! You are my savior!

Comment: Great! It got a little messy as you ran into other problems gradually, but I believe you can still mark my original answer as the solution because it answered the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script echoes and exits immediately, so it is not a deamon.  A daemon needs to continue running after invocation.

You need to have a program that behaves like a deamon in order to test its installation. The installation will not create a deamon out of a regular program. It will only prepare the environment for running it.

The question [How do you create a daemon in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473620/how-do-you-create-a-daemon-in-python) will give you more information how to write a proper daemon in Python.

Comment: I need to use a loop like `while true; do done` to know if it's working for example?

Comment: Yes, a deamon will typically run in some sort of infinite loop.

Comment: It's for a school project and I can't use libraries or existing code. So I do not know if using http://web.archive.org/web/20131017130434/http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/ is a good idea.

Comment: Sorry, I noticed the last sentence of your question just now, so I was a little confused.  I didn't realize that you don't care about writing the deamon itself.  The problem is that you need to have a program that behaves like a deamon in order to test its installation.  The installation will not create a deamon out of a regular program.  It will only prepare the environment for running it.

Comment: There is no problem. Yes exaclty, my program prepares the environment to receive a daemon. And my objective is to test if the environment is correctly configured to receive a daemon program. I thought that running a program with a loop would suffice.

Comment: Because to working, `gobatch` must use function `start` and `run`?

Comment: I feel that your init.d script (`fileContent`) is not complete.  It usually contains a case statement running different commands for start/status/stop/restart.

Comment: I think too, It's a good thing aha. However, in the case of start / stop / restart I do not know what to put as code.

Comment: The file /etc/init.d/gobatch (not /usr/bin/gobatch) should handle the start/stop/... commands.  Example: http://werxltd.com/wp/2012/01/05/simple-init-d-script-template

Comment: I already visited this page too. But on my tutorial https://openclassrooms.com/courses/faire-un-demon-sous-linux (in french sorry) the author never talk about thoses `case`. That's why I'm lost.

Comment: Maybe it's because his script starts `/etc/init.d/apache`. And  `/etc/init.d/apache` contains methods start/stop/restart.

Comment: I can see the function do_start() in section "Quelques options" and the case statement in "Sous d'autres distributions".  These may explain it (I don't know French).

Comment: Yes but `do_start(` is a function used to use program is in background. It is the next step of my install program.

Comment: I updated my question with the new `/etc/init.d/gobatch` file.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that once your `gobatch` prints the executions is done.

Try

```
#! /bin/bash
for i in $(seq 1 10)
do
    echo "it works !"
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: I copy this code into my `gobatch` file, I start my daemon and check the status directly, problem is the same.

Comment: Writing a deamon is not that easy.  This is why i linked a question which explains it instead of trying to explain it here.  For example the deamon typically runs in the background and uses a PID file.