# What is the recommended way of running a web application?

Tags: python, server, daemon

I'm doing a Python webserver (e.g. using Flask or Bottle, etc.), and I would like to start it, and be able to close the SSH terminal and let it running.

Which way would be the pythonic recommended way to do it?

1. [Create a daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473620/how-do-you-create-a-daemon-in-python), and use `python myapp.py start`, `python myapp.py stop`. However the python-daemon module has nearly no doc, *doesn't support triggering an action just before exiting* (I added a few lines to it [to support it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40561938/1422096)), so it's a bit a hack of an undocumented/not-really-maintained module, so even if it works, I'm not 100% happy with it.
2. Use `nohup python myapp.py &`, but then the drawback is that you have to `ps aux |grep py`, then find the relevant PID and `kill 12345` to stop it. Here again, it doesn't allow to do actions before stopping (e.g. save the database to disk, etc.), so it's not a very nice solution.
3. `screen -dmS myapp python myapp.py` to start, then you can log out from SSH terminal. Then later you can connect to it again with `screen -r myapp`, and then CTRL+C can stop it (provided `KeyboardInterrupt` is well handled). That's what I would use currently. But I'm not sure if using `screen` to let a server run forever is a good idea (what happens if the logging is really verybose? also is there a risk that introducing the `screen` layer would make it bloated?)
4. Another cleaner solution? I hope there's a cleaner solution than 1, 2, 3 that all have drawbacks.

Note: I would like to avoid installing new managers (upstart or supervisor), and do it with the least number of tools possible, to avoid new layers of complexity.

Comment: Write a service that is managed by systemd (or similar, eg upstart or supervisor).

Comment: @DanielRoseman I would like to avoid installing new managers (upstart or supervisor), and do it with the least number of tools possible, how would you do it?

Comment: You will probably want to use an application server like GUnicorn as well, so use systemd or supervisor to manage the GUnicorn process.

Comment: At least one of those things will already be installed, since it will be managing the system itself. If you have a recent distribution of Linux, it will probably be systemd.

Comment: what flavor of linux are you using?

Comment: @JimFactor Debian 8, I've never used systemd for such things because I wanted to do it with Python and simple tools only, and avoid having to create files outside of the app's folder (i.e. creating a systemd service involves creating files outside of the app's path, and then when you deploy it on another system, you need to remember those things, etc. and I feared it would not be as portable as other solutions).