# Create python loop as a "detached" child process

Tags: python, infinite-loop

I have an potentially infinite python 'while' loop that I would like to keep running even after the main script/process execution has been completed. Furthermore, I would like to be able to later kill this loop from a unix CLI if needed (ie. kill -SIGTERM PID), so will need the pid of the loop as well. How would I accomplish this? Thanks!

Loop:

```
args = 'ping -c 1 1.2.3.4'

while True:
    time.sleep(60)
    return_code = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    if return_code == 0:
        break
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473620/how-do-you-create-a-daemon-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, parent processes attempt to kill all their daemonic child processes when they exit. However, you can use `os.fork()` to create a completely new process:

```
import os

pid = os.fork()
if pid:
   #parent
   print("Parent!")
else:
   #child
   print("Child!")
```

Answer (score 0):

`Popen` returns an object which has the `pid`. According to the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

> Popen.pid
>   The process ID of the child process.
>
> Note that if you set the shell argument to True, this is the process ID of the spawned shell.

You would need to turnoff the `shell=True` to get the pid of the process, otherwise it gives the pid of the shell.

```
args = 'ping -c 1 1.2.3.4'

while True:
    time.sleep(60)
    with subprocess.Popen(args, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
        print('PID: {}'.format(proc.pid))
        ...
```