# Keep function running after main process completes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I would like to keep another Python process (Python function) running, even after the main process is completed.  Can this be done without using subprocess?

Currently if I run a non-daemonic process, then it will be automatically joined to the main process.

If I set the process to be daemon, then the child process will exit once the main process is complete.

How do I have another process keep running in the background, even after the main process is complete?

Comment: By definition subprocess is what you want , why you want to avoid subprocess?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you create a daemon in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473620/how-do-you-create-a-daemon-in-python)

Comment: Was just having some issues passing python object as the parameters with the subprocess