# Never-ending file existence check loop

Tags: python, loops, file, while-loop

I'm sorry, I'm a complete beginner but very fascinated by scripting automation. I'm trying to check for the existence of a file that arrives once in a while. I want to read it and then delete it. I can't figure out how to keep this action running without the `goto` Label feature.
Can anyone advise me please?

```
import os
import os.path
import time

path = os.path.exists('file.txt')

#loop
if path is True:
    print("File exists.")
    time.sleep(1)
    os.remove("file.txt")  # Remove the file.
# Now I need to start the loop again.
else:
    print("File doesn't exist")
    time.sleep(1)
# Now I need to start the loop again.
# And keep it running forever.
```

Comment: The simplest way is to drop the whole thing into a `while True` loop. Look into [daemons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473620/how-do-you-create-a-daemon-in-python) and [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) if you need fault tolerance.

Comment: Running it in a `while True` loop seems overly costly. How fast do you need to process this file?

Answer (score 0):

This is what "while" loops are for.

```
import os.path
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    if os.path.exists('file.txt'):
        print("File exists.")
        os.remove("file.txt")          #remove the file.
    else:
        print("File doesn't exist")
```

You can do this with a batch file.  You don't need Python.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works!
I didn't expect such a quick response.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a folder monitor which performs actions based on the event handling in the folder. I recommend using the **'watchdog'** library in python to monitor the folder for incoming or outgoing files while the **'subprocess'** library executes actions like reading and deleting. Refer to the code below

**Code:**

```
import subprocess
import time
import os

from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

def on_created(event):
    print("A File is arrived",os.path.basename(event.src_path))
    time.sleep(10)
    os.remove(event.src_path)

def on_deleted(event):
    print("File Deleted")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    event_handler= FileSystemEventHandler()

    event_handler.on_created=on_created
    event_handler.on_deleted=on_deleted

    path="A:/foldername" #"Enter the folder path" you want to monitor here

    observer= Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler,path,recursive=False)  #If recursive is set to be True it will check in the subdirectories for contents if a folder is added to our path
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(15)  # Sleeps for 15 seconds
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()   # The code terminates if we hit any key in the folder or else it keeps running for ever
    observer.join()
```

Also, if you want to read the file before deleting then add the file reading code in the on_created method before *"os.remove"* and the code should work fine for you now!